# Laravel dates on form model binding

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1

I got a model:

```
class ExampleModel extends Model {

    // ....
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y.m.d';
    protected $dates = ['first_date', 'second_date'];

    // ...
}
```

So when I'm indexing ExampleModel elements, the date format is correct (ex 2015.07.31)

But on an edit form it uses the default format: 2015-07-31 00:00:00

I'm using `Form::model()` binding.

I know I could use `getFirstDateAttribute()` but it's not the solution I'm looking for. Because it's not elegant at all and once I defined the `$dates` array, it should work automatically in every case.

So is it a bug maybe? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `But on an edit form it uses the default format: 2015-07-31 00:00:00` show the code where you checked it

Comment: Take a look at `illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, and you should be able to see how the `$dateFormat` was intended to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done this before, but it seems to work on a basic example I put together. Note that I'm just calling the `toArray` method on the model in the form opening tag.

```
{!! Form::model($exampleModel->toArray(), ['route' => ['example-models.update', $exampleModel->id]]) !!}
    {!! Form::label('first_date', 'First Date') !!}
    {!! Form::text('first_date') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The docs say that the `dateFormat` property determines the date format when the object is cast to json or an array.

Comment: You're good! I've also seen in the code that `Form::model()` accepts arrays as well and I've also found that to `Array()` works the way I want, I just somehow didn't put this two pieces of information together :-) Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by overriding Carbon's default date format:

```
Carbon\Carbon::setToStringFormat('Y.m.d');
```

But Kelly's answer is much better and more elegant, I just post this one as well, maybe someone will find this useful once.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't fully advise this as a fix because when you update the core you'll lose this fix, but maybe this should be posted as a pull request to Laravel's next version.*

In \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes update the asDate function as follows. As you can see from the comments the asDate function still returns a timestamp even though it's 00:00:00.

```
/**
     * Return a timestamp as DateTime object with time set to 00:00:00.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Carbon
     */
    protected function asDate($value)
    {
        $date = $this->asDateTime($value)->startOfDay();
        $date->setToStringFormat($this->getDateFormat());
        return $date;
    }
```

This allows you to control the format of a date from the model (note I'm differentiating between a date and datetime). Then use the casts variable to cast your variable to date format.

```
protected $casts = [
    'start_date' => 'date',
    'end_date' => 'date'
  ];
  protected $dateFormat =  'Y-m-d';
```

The $dates variable cannot differentiate between a date and a datetime.

**UPDATE**
The real problem is the form model binding skips the helper function of the FormBuilder class. As you can see if you inspect \Collective\Html\FormBuilder::date

```
/**
 * Create a date input field.
 *
 * @param  string $name
 * @param  string $value
 * @param  array  $options
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
 */
public function date($name, $value = null, $options = [])
{
    if ($value instanceof DateTime) {
        $value = $value->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    return $this->input('date', $name, $value, $options);
}
```

It is correctly formatting date to 'Y-m-d' as specified in HTML5 spec. However at this point $value is actually null. So you have to update the generic input function.

```
/**
 * Create a form input field.
 *
 * @param  string $type
 * @param  string $name
 * @param  string $value
 * @param  array  $options
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
 */
public function input($type, $name, $value = null, $options = [])
{
    ...

    //$value is null here
    if (! in_array($type, $this->skipValueTypes)) {

        //$value is fetched based on hierarchy set by
        $value = $this->getValueAttribute($name, $value);

        //necessary duplicate code to format date value
        if ($type == 'date' && $value instanceof DateTime) {
            $value = $value->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**UPDATE** There is no need to update vendor code. Check out FormModelAccessors

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding

Comment: Testing further. I don't think this is a valid answer as Carbon's setToStringFormat is a static variable and affects all Carbon dates. If you have one cast to date then all will be cast to date. It seems the best you can do is either return it as a string or as laravel has it with a date and the time is zeroed out.

Comment: Maybe instead of replacing vendor code, methods could be just overriden  in parent class